# Regex.Replace Method

Tags: regex, string, replace

I want to use Regex.Replace method.I will search
"new long?((long)" expressions in very long string and will make the following change.

Before:

```
OracleParameter[] array = new OracleParameter[]
{
    new OracleParameter("p_op_adi", OracleDbType.Varchar2, p_op_adi, ParameterDirection.Input),
    new OracleParameter("p_tip_no", OracleDbType.Int64, p_tip_no, ParameterDirection.Input),
    new OracleParameter("p_islem", OracleDbType.Varchar2, p_islem, ParameterDirection.Input),
    new OracleParameter("p_raise", OracleDbType.Varchar2, p_raise, ParameterDirection.Input),
    new OracleParameter("p_durum", OracleDbType.Int64, null, ParameterDirection.Output),
    new OracleParameter("p_mesaj", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 4000, null, ParameterDirection.Output)
};
sMan.ExecuteSP("FRM_USER.user_yetki_kontrol_islem", array);
p_durum = ((array[4].Value != System.DBNull.Value) ? new long?((long)array[4].Value) : null);
p_mesaj = array[5].Value.ToString();
```

After Regex:

```
OracleParameter[] array = new OracleParameter[]
{
    new OracleParameter("p_op_adi", OracleDbType.Varchar2, p_op_adi, ParameterDirection.Input),
    new OracleParameter("p_tip_no", OracleDbType.Int64, p_tip_no, ParameterDirection.Input),
    new OracleParameter("p_islem", OracleDbType.Varchar2, p_islem, ParameterDirection.Input),
    new OracleParameter("p_raise", OracleDbType.Varchar2, p_raise, ParameterDirection.Input),
    new OracleParameter("p_durum", OracleDbType.Int64, null, ParameterDirection.Output),
    new OracleParameter("p_mesaj", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 4000, null, ParameterDirection.Output)
};
sMan.ExecuteSP("FRM_USER.user_yetki_kontrol_islem", array);
p_durum = abcde(array[4].Value);
p_mesaj = array[5].Value.ToString();
```

Note that I must catch array index number 4.

Comment: Does your intended change only affect the last but one line? What's the purpose of pasting the rest of the code if so? Is there a ternary operator to remove in each case? Showing a few more examples - I assume there's plenty, since you want to automate the process - would be instructive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should do exaclty what you want:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = @"OracleParameter[] array = new OracleParameter[]
            {
                new OracleParameter('p_op_adi', OracleDbType.Varchar2, p_op_adi, ParameterDirection.Input),
                p_durum = ((array[4].Value != System.DBNull.Value) ? new long?((long)array[4].Value) : null);
                p_durum = ((array[4].Value != System.DBNull.Value) ? new long?((long)array[4].Value) : null);
            ";

        string pattern = @"^(?<varname>[^=]*)=.*new long\?\(\(long\)(?<arrayval>[^)]*).*?$";
        string replacement = "${varname} = abcde(${arrayval});";

        string output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement, RegexOptions.Multiline);
        Console.WriteLine(output);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

It gatters variable name and array value and uses these as substitutions in the replacement part.

Comment: That was something that I need..Thanks WouterH

Answer (score 0):

this regex select full string `(?m)^.*?new long\?\(\(long\).*?$`

```
string res = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?m)^.*?new long\?\(\(long\).*?$", "p_durum = abcde(array[4].Value);");
```